# How do I apply style to standard lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, style

I'm familiar with docs to create your own custom lightning design elements and design tokens, how can they be applied to a standard component on a specific page?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can only use design elements / design tokens with custom Lightning components.   :(

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Shane's answer.
What you would want to do instead is to override actions to point to your custom components, where styling can be applied.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_action_overrides_basics.htm

Comment: This answer is not super helpful.  Can you give a specific example of what that would look like in practice - e.g. using design tokens on the custom component as the OP asked?